# Do we need an Acronyms tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have 4 questions with the tag [acronyms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acronyms). It has no tag wiki, but seems to have been used to mark questions that ask about the use of acronyms/abbreviations in otherwise unrelated record sets.

I don't think it helps us organise our questions; nor that it is a tag that anyone would choose to follow; nor that it makes it easier to locate duplicate questions; nor that it assists with SEO.

Am I missing a reason to keep this tag? Or should it be burninated?

Comment: That tag has now been burninated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we need a tag for it. What is the likelihood that someone would want to subscribe to a site to get all the new acronym questions?

Anyone looking for prior questions about acronyms can easily search for the word instead.

Comment: I've upvoted and removed/rolled back the [tag:acronyms] from the three questions that I added this tag to yesterday.  The one remaining already had it, and although it is about an acronym that term does not appear in its body or title.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I've edited that one question to be tagged with terminology rather than acronyms.